# System.IO.IOException: An unexpected network error occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net

Our website works perfectly at day time and throws this error mostly at night time. I'm new to .net so please tell me if this is something to handle from the backend of code or inside server settings. Also how can I identify the exact page to look for the errors?

```
[IOException: An unexpected network error occurred.]
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +7718492
System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +7478337
System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +264
System.IO.BinaryReader.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count) +85
Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSIndexInput.ReadInternal(Byte[] b, Int32 offset, Int32 len) +332
Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.ReadBytes(Byte[] b, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Boolean useBuffer) +647
Lucene.Net.Index.CSIndexInput.ReadInternal(Byte[] b, Int32 offset, Int32 len) +242
Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.Refill() +410
Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.ReadByte() +78
Lucene.Net.Store.IndexInput.ReadVInt() +60
Lucene.Net.Index.TermBuffer.Read(IndexInput input, FieldInfos fieldInfos) +64
Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentTermEnum.Next() +244
Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentTermEnum.ScanTo(Term term) +110
Lucene.Net.Index.TermInfosReader.Get(Term term, Boolean useCache) +633
Lucene.Net.Index.TermInfosReader.Terms(Term term) +45
Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentReader.Terms(Term t) +71
Lucene.Net.Index.MultiTermEnum..ctor(IndexReader topReader, IndexReader[] readers, Int32[] starts, Term t) +227
Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.Terms(Term term) +80
Lucene.Net.Search.NumericRangeTermEnum.Next() +562
Lucene.Net.Search.NumericRangeTermEnum..ctor(NumericRangeQuery enclosingInstance, IndexReader reader) +2295
Lucene.Net.Search.NumericRangeQuery.GetEnum(IndexReader reader) +59
Lucene.Net.Search.ConstantScoreAutoRewrite.Rewrite(IndexReader reader, MultiTermQuery query) +272
Lucene.Net.Search.MultiTermQuery.Rewrite(IndexReader reader) +54
Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery.Rewrite(IndexReader reader) +503
Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Rewrite(Query original) +68
Lucene.Net.Search.Query.Weight(Searcher searcher) +72
Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.CreateWeight(Query query) +42
Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Search(Query query, Collector results) +43
Seamless.CMS.WebUI.CustomControls.SCLuceneHelper.SearchSCData(SearchCriteria criteria, SeamlessList`1& listResultItem, String& filter, Query& highlighterQuery) +2519
Seamless.CMS.WebUI.CustomControls.SCSearchList.Find(SearchCriteria searchConditions) +128
Seamless.CMS.WebUI.CustomControls.SCSearchList.InitialSearch() +712
Seamless.CMS.WebUI.CustomControls.SCSearchList.PageLoad() +690
Seamless.CMS.WebUI.CustomControls.SCSearchList.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

---

I found this under search page.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Seamless.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Seamless.CMS.WebUI.CustomControls
{
public partial class Search : ControlBase, ISeamlessCMSControl
{

    #region Properties
    public string searchResultUrl
    {
        set { ViewState["searchResultUrl"] = value; }
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["searchResultUrl"] == null)
                ViewState["searchResultUrl"] = "";
            return (string)ViewState["searchResultUrl"];
        }
    }
    #endregion


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            if (Request.QueryString["query"] != null)
                txtSearch.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["query"].ToString());

    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(CMSSettings.GetVirtualPathRoot() + searchResultUrl + "?keyword=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtSearch.Text.Replace("+", "").Replace(".", "").Trim()));
    }

    #region ISeamlessCMSControl Members

    public List<CustomControlProperty> GetProperties()
    {
        List<CustomControlProperty> ccpList = new List<CustomControlProperty>();
        CustomControlProperty ccp = new CustomControlProperty();

        ccp = new CustomControlProperty();
        ccp.controlType = CustomControlProperty.ControlTypes.Textbox;
        ccp.name = "searchResultUrl";
        ccp.description = "The url containing the search result list";
        ccp.propertyType = "string";
        ccp.controlValues.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
        ccpList.Add(ccp);

        return ccpList;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: It's trying to read a file and fails but you need to give us more information, not just the error.

Comment: its likely in the class: `SCSearchList` in the `PageLoad()`

Comment: Thanks @Szymon What kind of information you need? Please tell me

Comment: The code that throws that exception.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure which page to look for. Can I get a hint from the stack trace above? The site has two sections. The frontend and the admin panel